# How to shift accessibility focus on RecyclerView's first element on some action?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback, accessibility

I am new with android accessibility - `TalkBack`. 
I am aware of basic things like `contentDescription`, `importantForAaccessibility` and how they make node tree, etc.

In my problem, I want to shift accessibility focus on `RecyclerView`'s first element on some action.

Usually `someView.requestFocus()` or `someView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` works.
But it seems to not working as expected in `RecyclerView`.

I have tried to solve it by:

1. `android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite"` but it only announce that list is there. But it doesn't go on an element with accessibility focus.
2. By focusing the first element from the adapter - but it's a bad idea to do so!

Other than that, `android:accessibilityTraversalAfter` and `android:accessibilityTraversalBefore` also don't work well with a list view in android.

```java
someView.requestFocus()
someView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

Comment: In general, it isn't a good idea to set focus; that is something that is best left to accessibility service like Talkback to figure out. If focus is assigned on an app-specific basis, the experience for the user of accessibility services becomes fragmented.

Comment: In my case, While the user visits a screen, API call is made. 
Once It gives a response, Recycler View will appear. When this view is being visible, It should focus on that list. 
I think it would be easy for users if accessibility focus detects this change.

Comment: @DharaVamja Hey sorry if I write you here but I seen you answered a lot of questions about accessibility and I would like to ask you a question too. Do you know how to have a listener for accessibility focus in Android? Something that, when a button, label or else (a View in general) become focused by the screen reader, I can add a behavior to (like simply have a log saying "I am focused")? Thanks

Comment: @Poli97 Hey, sorry for late replay, Yes, I have read something about it when doing R & D on it, but haven't tried it as I didn't get any use case for the same. 

If you are facing issues in a nested scroll view or simple scroll view - jump child view problem, then there's a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RecyclerView's `getChildAt()` method worked for me.

```
recyclerView.getChildAt(0).requestFocus()
recyclerView.getChildAt(0).sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

Answer (score 2):

Request Focus with Specific `ViewId` and gets the first element of that node.

Comment: I think `viewId`  won't work with accessibility focus shift. We will need `View` itself to get focused. Thank you for your answer it helped me to get a solution. :)